# Input Audio from TV to GPU via HDMI's ARC Technology then Output to Speakers Connected to a STX

Tags: audio, hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card, sound-card, hdtv

Reason:
I noticed 4 devices on the "recording" section of program I am using.

[Screenshot of NVidia AUX input connectors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjCin.png)

I want to be able to access these hopefully to pass audio back from my TV to my PC, SO that I can in theory play the audio from my Xbox or cable box though some decent speakers. my TV is Audio Return Channel(ARC) capable.

The bigger question isn't that if this is possible but what exactly "are" those AUX inputs anyway? i know 3 things, 1) There are 4 Audio Outputs on my GPU (4 video outputs including DP DVI-D DVI-I and HDMI), 2) These AUX inputs must correspond with the Video Ouputs, either as "virtual inputs" to record off of, actual inputs from the ports themselves. 3. ARC exists therefore my GPU must be capable of it.

So is this even possible, and if not what are these "Recording Devices" really for?

If it is then how?

Could it possibly be a glitch with the program?

specs:

- windows 7/10 (going back to 10 in the near future)
- gtx 760 (input to)
- i5 6600k
- gigabyte z170x-gamming 5
- asus xonar esssence STX (where i want to output said audio)
- insignia TV w/ roku... (don't really remember the model too lazy to look it up, also what i want to input from)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically Not Possible in case anyone is wondering. well is shouldn't be possible, at least not with the way GPUs are manufactured and configured today, the bottom line is that these inputs are more likely "virtual" audio tap devices then "physical" inputs... of course, you would have to ask an engineer, and good luck coercing an engineer at nVidia OR AMD into telling you if that is even a thing that is technically possible. (just like balanced audio outputs or dual headphone or separate mic headphone outputs on phones, technically possible but little interest or need plus technical design preference issues for something like that to be implemented, bet you never thought that might be cool to have before i mentioned it) so to put it simply even if it was possible little demand for it exists thus it isn't implemented or developed. it would be special use cases and audio nuts techies that would use such a feature and well very few of them at best. it isn't worth the investment to implement thus not going to happen. not to mention there would have to be driver support for it, there isn't and windows doesn't know what to do... so yeah, best bet if you stumble across this type of thing and are wondering the same thing as i was, try Linux there might be something there if it is even possible.

Comment: Please consider formatting your answer. It's a bit difficult to read as a [wall of text](http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Wall_of_Text).